# Cant find the way to use a Keyframe animation via Jquery (.css, .animate)

Tags: html, jquery, css, animation, keyframe

My html

```
        <fieldset class="field_one">
            <legend>Character Creation <i class="fa-solid fa-signs-post"></i></legend>
            <div id="message">...............</div>
            <img src="./image/index1.png" id="mainImage" alt="">
            <div class="button"><a href="#" id="btnImage">¡Generate Character!</a></div> 
            <div class="button"><a href="#" id="btnName">¡Generate Nickname!</a></div>
        </fieldset>
```

My css keyframe

```
@keyframes rainbow {
    0%   {color:red;}
    25%  {color:blue;}
    50%  {color:gold;}
    75%  {color:greenyellow;}
    100% {color:red;}
}
```

My jquery js

```
$('fieldset').hover(function() {
        $(this).css({"animation":"rainbow","font-size":"18pt"}, 1000);
});
```

Is for a work i need to do and i cant really find a way to make it work with jquery (i know that is way easier with plain css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a class with your animation rules and then use addClass()

```js
$('fieldset').hover(function() {
   $(this).addClass('rainbowAnim');
});
```

```css
@keyframes rainbow {
    0%   {color:red;}
    25%  {color:blue;}
    50%  {color:gold;}
    75%  {color:greenyellow;}
    100% {color:red;}
}
.rainbowAnim {
  -webkit-animation: rainbow 5s infinite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="field_one">
    <legend>Character Creation <i class="fa-solid fa-signs-post"></i></legend>
    <div id="message">...............</div>
    <img src="./image/index1.png" id="mainImage" alt="">
    <div class="button"><a href="#" id="btnImage">¡Generate Character!</a></div> 
    <div class="button"><a href="#" id="btnName">¡Generate Nickname!</a></div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this works great! i was losing my mind with this...